# When are interpolated string evaluated?

Tags: c#, clr

I have following code:

```
    internal class Constants
    {
        internal static string Source { get; set; }

        #region EvaluationRepository
        internal static string QUERY_001 = $@"
select
  e.*
from {Source} e
where
  e.id = @Id
";

        internal static string QUERY_002 = $@"
select
  e.*
from {Source} e
where
  e.statusid=@StatusId
  and e.begindate >= @FromDate
  and e.enddate <= @ToDate
";

        internal static string QUERY_003
        {
            get
            {
                return $@"
select
  d.statusid [StatusId],
  count(1) [Count]
from
  (select e.statusid
  from {Source} e
  where e.begindate >= @FromDate and e.enddate <= @ToDate) d
group by d.statusid
";
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

The only time `{Source}` is filled is when I expose the query as a **property**. *(QUERY_003)*
It doesn't work when exposed as a **field**. *(QUERY_001, QUERY_002)*

Can anyone explain why? Because of the *staticness* (not sure if that's a word)?

Sorry for the verbatim interpolation noise for the SQL :)

Comment: Really, string interpolation is a red herring here. You're effectively asking "when are field initializers evaluated?".

Comment: Yes because when I expose the string as a field {Source} is not filled.

Comment: It is because it's `static` which means it will create the value the first time it initializes the `static` class so changing `Source` after that has no effect.  But the property will initialize a new `string` when you access it thus using the latest value for `Source`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done at runtime. It's equivalent (down to the IL generated) to using `string.Format`.

The reason the *fields* are not properly filled is because `Source` is empty when it initially executes (when the static class is initialized).

Comment: YES! That's it. I could trick it with a static constructor and give it a default value to prove it.

Comment: also, I rather see String.Format instead of string.Format *trollface

Comment: @grmbl `string` and `String` are the same thing. `string` is just a language keyword that is an alias for the class `String`.

Comment: I know. I guess it's OCD for me to not use keywords as objects.

Comment: @Rob Your answer is rather ambiguous - all variables are evaluated at runtime. It would be more helpful to say that grmbl's string initializations are evaluated once, when the containing class's static constructor is invoked (they require non-trivial initialization). For more help, see [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).